# How do I solve the INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error at Android Studio 3.5?

Tags: android, android-studio

I developed an application for android 5.0, but when built-in Android Studio 3.5 for a device with Android 5.0, show an **error**:

> The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

PS: If you create a new project on Android Studio 3.5, and check minimum version android: Android 5.0 (21), you have the same error.

Comment: You are using a device or an emulator?

Comment: Usually this issue will come when your device or emulator running out of space.

Comment: Emulator, I set 8GB to storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to do below steps,

```
1. Navigate to the /Users/user_xxx/.android/avd/Nexus6API22.avd 
2. Delete all the locks via: $rm *.lock 
3. Wiped Data via AVD Manager 
4. Restart the Emulator 
5. Success.
```

Comment: It should be enough to wipe data via AVD manager and cold boot your emulator from AVD as well.